# AWK - request for clarification example

Tags: awk, gsub

I have 3 examples of using gsub:

**1.**

```
echo -e "A A\nB B\nC C" | awk '{gsub($(!/B/),"",$1); print $1 "\t" $2}' 
    A
B   B
    C
```

**2.**

```
$ echo -e "A A\nB B\nC C" | awk '{gsub($(!/B/),"",$2); print $1 "\t" $2}'
A   
B   B
C
```

**3.**

```
$ echo -e "A A\nB B\nC C" | awk '{gsub($(!/B/),"",$0); print $1 "\t" $2}'



.
```

Why in the 3 example awk nothing printed? Does awk should not print?:

```
B   B
```

Please explain 3 examples.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't understand the use of a negation in the gsub regex, what do you expect it to do and do you have a reference for this, or are you just trying to figure out how to split on `/[^B]/`?

Comment: @tripleee, Why can not I use gsub regex negation `$(!/B/)`? Can you explain that?

Comment: No, can *you* explain what you think it means? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I just want to know if you can use this form of negation `$(!/B/)`? If you can not, why?

Comment: If it does what you think it does, go ahead; but maybe explain what it's supposed to do to the rest of us.  It looks to me like you are trying to accomplish something which is probably not working the way you expect it to, but we can't help you figure that out if you don't tell us what you expect.  Welp, your call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key point for me is this: `$(!/B/)`. Very awkward. What does it mean (or at least I guess it means)?

- **/B/**: It tries to match the letter `B` in the whole line. If it matches returns `1`, otherwise `0`.
- **!**: Negates the previous result code.
- **$()**: It returns the whole line (`$0`) or the first field (`$1`) after resolving previous instructions.

The third case is ok.

- When `B` matches the instruction is `gsub( $0, "", $0 )`, an empty line. That's clear.
- When `B` doesn't match the instruction is `gsub( $1, "", $0 )`. So, as both letters are the same and `gsub` replaces many times by line, it deletes all characters. Add another different character and you will see the difference.

For example:

```
echo -e "A A 1\nB B 1\nC C 1" | awk '{gsub($(!/B/),"",$0); print $1 "\t" $2}'
```

That yields:

```
1

1
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I still have this question.
Why can not I use gsub regex negation `$(!/B/)`? Can you explain that?

Comment: @Tedee12345: You can use whatever you want, but it's confusing. It's not easy to get the point at first sight of what you (or whoever that wrote it) want to achieve.